# Qlogic HBA Performance Monitoring Issuse

Tags: linux, centos, fc

I used QConvergeConsoleCLI Version 2.7.0 (Build 6) and  "qaucli -gs 1" command in CentOS 7 for monitoring FC port performance. Despite having a load on FC, it showed zero as IOPS.

I tested this scenario on different hardware (server and HBA) and OS (Centos 7&8 and Ubuntu), but the problem remains.

OS = CentOS 7
Kernel Version = 5.4.200
QConvergeConsoleCLI Version = 2.7.0 (Build 6)
QLA Driver = 10.01.00.19-k
HBA = QLE2694L and HPAJ764A
[image]